# UIPickerView selection link to UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview, segue

How do I link a `UIPicker` view on one scene to a `UITableViewController`? I have a picker view in one view controller populated with a number of categories, I want to segue to a table view controller when a category is selected/pressed.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the segue in the Storyboard by Ctrl-dragging from the view controller to the new `TableViewController` (don't link from the picker, link from the view controller in which it appears).  Select the segue and give it an appropriate identifier.  In your `UIPickerView` delegate, implement the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method, and save the selected rows/components to properties.  Then invoke `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to trigger the segue.

Separately, as part of the `prepareForSegue` method, read the properties you previously saved, and set the relevant properties of the segue destination view controller.

NB you may find, though, that this will trigger if the user hesitates whilst spinning through the picker view options.